# How make a perfect curve with css?

Tags: html, css

I want to create my navbar something like this

[Navbar](https://techfest.org/)

And this is what I have created one side div container but the curves are not perfect of my div and i need to make this for both sides for both side I will use flex box but my main focus is to create that same curves.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .left {
            border-radius: 0px 5px 100px 0px / 100px 30px 100px 0px;
            border: 0px solid #800000;
            background-color: red;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 100px;
            width: 500px;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="left">
        s
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: This article may guide you in the right direction (https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-fancy-corners-in-css/).  Your example website just uses svg images not borders btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work here you go :)

The website you gave uses .svg images to create this curve effect.

And with `display: flex;` makes them inline.

```html
<body>
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background: black;
        }

        .navbar {
            display: flex;
        }

    </style>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="left">
            <img src="https://techfest.org/2021/home/Navbar/Logo.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <img src="https://techfest.org/2021/home/Navbar/TN.svg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: yeah but it's difficult to make it responsive and use it as navbar. so I want to create it using html and css.

Answer (score -1):

This will need Javascript, search for burger navbar CSS design using Javascript on YouTube.

Comment: Everything visual can pretty much be made with HTML and CSS only.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).